# How do I "WaitMoreThanOne" in a Semaphore?

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

Is there a way I can wait for more than one Release() in a Semaphore?

Say I have something like this:

```
class GoRunners {

    Semaphore runnersSemaphore;

    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

    private void RunForestRun(object aRunner) {
        runnersSemaphore.Wait();
        Runner runner = (Runner)aRunner;
        results.Add(runner.Run());
        runnersSemaphore.Release();
    }

    private List<Result> Go() {
        List<Runners>() runners = CreateSomeRunners();
        runnersSemaphore = new Semaphore(2, 2); // At most two threads at once
        runners.ForEach((runner) => new Thread(RunForestRun).Start(runner); )}
        runnersSemaphore.WaitFor(runners.Count); //How do I do this?
        return results;
    }
}
```

I know I can use multiple `WaitOne()`s inside the loop, but that just doesn't look good. But if there is no other way, I'm fine with it. If there is another mechanism that achieves what I want that's OK as well (I used to do stuff like this in Java using Semaphores, so my mind went in that direction).

**Note: I'm locked in .NET 3.5 :(**

Comment: Too bad you can't do .NET 4.0. [`CountdownEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx) does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: If the semaphore is simply for checking for completion of the threads, it would be simpler to just `thread.Join()` on each runner thread.

Comment: @itsme86 I'm sorry, I wrote that question in a hurry and forgot to mention/code that I must run at most X threads at the same time.

Comment: This question is completely different than the one this is marked as duplicate of. Plus, the answer in that one is for .NET 1.1, which is five years old. And it asks me to download a sample which is an .exe file; errm, nope.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your rate limiting code inside the foreach loop, that way the loop does not exit until after all of the runners have started. Once you have done that you only need to wait for the remaining two runners to finish before you return the result.

```
class GoRunners {

    Semaphore runnersSemaphore;

    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

    private void RunForestRun(object aRunner) {
        try {
            Runner runner = (Runner)aRunner;

            var result = runner.Run(); 
            lock(results)
            {
                results.Add(result)//List is not thread safe, you need to lock on it or use a different threadsafe collection (I don't know if there are any in .NET 3.5)
            }
        }
        finally { //A little safety in case a execption gets thrown inside "runner.Run()"
            runnersSemaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    const int MAX_RUNNERS = 2; //I hate magic numbers in code if they get spread across more than one line, move the max out to a const variable.

    private List<Result> Go() {
        List<Runners>() runners = CreateSomeRunners();
        runnersSemaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_RUNNERS, MAX_RUNNERS); // At most two threads at once
        foreach(var runner in runners)
        {
            runnersSemaphore.WaitOne(); //This goes in here now. New threads will not be started unless there is less than 2 runners running.
            new Thread(RunForestRun).Start(runner);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_RUNNERS; i++) {
            runnersSemaphore.WaitOne(); //Wait for the currently running runners to finish.
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the external WaitOne() for this, otherwise only two calls to it would return and the remaining would be locked forever. This is a little different from what I had in mind (this locks before creating the threads instead on locking on the threads themselves), but this approach should work as well.

Comment: If you don't have it in the for loop you will need some other way to track when the threads are done. It will either require a thread safe counter of some kind or performing a `Join()` on all of the started threads.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, limiting the amount of running threads with a semaphore and then waiting for all of them to finish using a list with `Join()`